# How to limit child nodes to a specific number in neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j, and stuck in a very peculiar problem to limit child nodes of  particular parent nodes.Please take a look at the query that I wrote :

```
MATCH (l:Presentation_Layer)-[c:CONTAINS]-(o) 
MATCH (l1:Business_Layer)-[r:CONTAINS]-(o1:Object)
MATCH (l2:Data_Layer)-[r2:CONTAINS]-(o2:Object)
WITH l,l1,l2,c,r,r2,o,o1,o2 LIMIT 100
OPTIONAL MATCH(l3:Layer)-[d:REFERENCES]-(l4:Layer)
RETURN *
```

And the result is as follows:(Refer screenshot)[image]

Here, I have three parent nodes:
1.Presentation Layer
2.Business Layer
3.Data Layer

I want to display exactly lets say 50 child nodes for each of the parent nodes.But when I use limit it does not limit the number of nodes (but to the number of rows to display) for a particular parent node and randomly displays the graph.Each parent nodes have a relationship of type :CONTAINS with the child nodes and number of child nodes is greater than 100 for each parent node.
Could it be possible to limit the child nodes to a certain number, for each parent node viz. Each parent node shall display 50 child nodes.
Can we do it with cypher query 
Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT does not apply to the results of a MATCH, it applies to the total records/rows returned.

Here's a knowledge base article on how to [limit the results of a match per row](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/).

The trick will be to get all your parent nodes under a single variable, which you should be able to do with a WHERE clause an OR logic on the labels you need.

Here's an example of using the `apoc.cypher.run()` approach:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n:Presentation_Layer OR n:Business_Layer OR n:Data_Layer
CALL apoc.cypher.run("
  MATCH (n)-[r:CONTAINS]-(o) 
  RETURN n, r, o 
  LIMIT 50", 
  {n:n}) YIELD value
RETURN value.n, value.r, value.o
```

EDIT

If you need the relationships between all the given parent nodes, you can use an APOC Procedure for that, but you'll need to pass it the collection of parent node ids. Here's one way you can do this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n:Presentation_Layer OR n:Business_Layer OR n:Data_Layer
WITH collect(n) as parents, collect(id(n)) as ids
CALL apoc.algo.cover(ids) YIELD rel
WITH parents, collect(rel) as parentRels
UNWIND parents as n
CALL apoc.cypher.run("
  MATCH (n)-[r:CONTAINS]-(o) 
  RETURN n, r, o 
  LIMIT 50", 
  {n:n}) YIELD value
RETURN value.n, value.r, value.o, parentRels
```

Comment: Added on to the query that should also return the parent rels